# What is wrong with my if statement for altering a column?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to write a for loop and if statement that correct a column. This is the code I tried to do. If time is not `NA` and `CA = 0` then `CA = 1`. If time is `NA` and `CA = 0` then `CA = 0`. Else `CA = 2`

Data `dfz`:

| Time | CA | FO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 0 | 0 |
| 1000 | 0 | 0 |
| 500 | 0 | 0 |
| 800 | 0 | 0 |
| 1200 | 0 | 0 |
| 1300 | 0 | 0 |
| 1800 | 0 | 0 |
| 1500 | 0 | 0 |
| NA | 0 | 0 |
| NA | 0 | 0 |
| NA | 0 | 0 |

This is the code I have tried but keep getting all 2 or 0:

```
for (x in dfz$Time) {
  for(y in dfz$CA){
    if(!(is.na(x)) & y == 0){
      dfz$CA = 1
      }else if ((is.na(x)) & y == 0){
        dfz$CA = 0
        }else{
          dfz$CA = dfz$CA
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the language you're using

Comment: This is in R language

Comment: Could you edit your question to include sample data and your desired outcome?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)